# Biblatex defernumbers=true and tabular corrupts bibliography

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am currently writing my thesis and i wanted to compare my results with other published works.
Doing this I noticed, that if I cite a source for the first time from within the table, all bibliography entries read 0.

Here is the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false, language=english, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

    \begin{table}[t]
    \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|X|}\hline
        \cite{test} \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the corresponding .bib file

```latex
@InProceedings{test,
  author    = {Test},
  title     = {Testtitle}
}
```

If defernumbers=true is removed it results in a usable bibliography.

A similar problem seems to be mentioned in [Reference [0] with defernumbers=true](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299336/reference-0-with-defernumbers-true?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is this known/expected behavior? In any case I would be glad if someone could provide me with a workaround if available.

Thanks in advance

PS: Compile order was **pdflatex** **biber** **pdflatex** **pdflatex**

Comment: Should be this bug that surfaced again a while ago: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/242. A fix has been committed and will be available with the next `biblatex` update (*edit*: I just verified that the issue from the MWE is resolved in the `dev` version of `biblatex`). The issue is also discussed at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/468475/35864, where a workaround is offered.

Comment: Any news here? Did the linked question help you work around the issue?

Comment: Any news here? If there are no new developments here in due time I think I will vote to close this question as a duplicate of the one I linked above since it is about the same issue and there is a workaround available.

Comment: I voted to close the question as a duplicate of the linked one. If you have any issues getting the workaround suggested there to work properly for you, please ask a new question detailing what you tried and how it didn't work.